# Help getting "correct" mysql count from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

Hey guys, I have this query.

```
"SELECT COUNT(purchase_log.id), purchase_log.date_purchased, purchase_log.total_cost, purchase_log.payment_status, cart_contents.product_name, members.first_name, members.last_name, members.email FROM `purchase_log` LEFT JOIN `cart_contents` ON purchase_log.id = cart_contents.purchase_id LEFT JOIN `members` ON purchase_log.member_id = members.id";
```

As you can see I have 3 different tables I am trying to draw data from.  After running this query, it returns with the count of 9.  That is actually the total number of rows in the table "cart_contents" but what I want is for it to return 5 because the table "purchase_log" contains the total transaction per row and each transaction can have 1 or more rows in table "cart_contents".

So how can I form the query to count the right amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
>   purchase_log.id),
>   purchase_log.date_purchased,
>   purchase_log.total_cost,
>   purchase_log.payment_status,
>   cart_contents.product_name,
>   members.first_name, members.last_name,
>   members.email FROM `purchase_log` LEFT
>   JOIN `cart_contents` ON
>   purchase_log.id =
>   cart_contents.purchase_id LEFT JOIN
>   `members` ON purchase_log.member_id =
>   members.id

Comment: Yes this worked...I actually tried this but I was stupid and I put DISTINCT COUNT(purchase_log.id) instead of what you have...Thanks for the help!